# jQuery text ticker pause on hover

Tags: jquery, ticker

I found this text ticker: http://jsfiddle.net/4mTMw/8/

How can I pause the text on hover?

I tried:

```
marquee.hover(function() {
    clearInterval(marquee);
    clearInterval(mar);
    marquee.css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
    mar.css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
    marquee.stop();
    mar.stop();
});
```

Nothing works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery pause on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439830/jquery-pause-on-hover)

Comment: Not quite, clearInterval(mar.marquee); doesn't stop it

Comment: use `clearInterval(marquee.data("interval"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qL93omsj/2/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var marquee = $('div.marquee');
  marquee.each(function() {
    var mar = $(this),
      indent = mar.width();
    mar.marquee = function() {
      indent--;
      mar.css('text-indent', indent);
      if (indent < -1 * mar.children('div.marquee-text').width()) {
        indent = mar.width();
      }
    };
    mar.data('interval', setInterval(mar.marquee, 1000 / 60));
    mar.hover(function() {
      clearInterval($(this).data("interval"));
    }, function() {
      $(this).data('interval', setInterval(mar.marquee, 1000 / 60));
    });
  });
});
```

The Interval is saved to the Data. You will need to use `clearInterval()` on that to pause it.

Comment: would you know how to stop and start it on click? copying the 'hover' and changing it for 'click' doesn't stop it and actually doubles the speed.

Comment: @linuxoid `hover` accepts two functions, where `click` only accepts one. So you need to build in a toggle flag. When the marquee starts, add a data flag that can be `true` / `false`. Then in your click function, you can check this flag and perform stop / start of the marquee.